# How to know the path of the war of the current application in tomcat

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, deployment

I've a tomcat (with JSF) application. I want to know the path of the war of the current application.

I've tried the following code to know where tomcat is
`((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getRealPath("")`

However, after I add  `antiResourceLocking="true"` to the context definition, the previous command is returning a temporal directory.

I've been debugging, and I see that in the

```
((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext())
```

There is a variable named context with one attribute named docBase, which contains the info that I need. However I can't get this by any way.

The reason of this is: I'm doing an auto-update system, so I need to get the current war in order to apply some patches to it. Therefore I need the current war file path.

Comment: Why do you need to know the root location of the unexpanded WAR? What's the functional requirement behind this need? There may be better solutions.

Comment: I'm doing an auto-update system, so I need to get the current war in orther to apply some patches to it. Therefore I need the current war file path.

Comment: So I would personaly suggest you to define a different path somewhere else than inside war. Modifying the content on the fly may produce some unwanted side-effects, as it is not intended by servlet spec.

Comment: The only thing I need is the path of the war, so I can copy it, modify the war and redeploy it using tomcat manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either it is not possible, or no one knows how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

**Honestly I have to say this is not possible, or only with some very fault-prone hack** like this

I presume that the real class of `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()` id in this case `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext`

So you may acces `docBase` like this

```
javax.faces.context.ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
if(externalContext instanceof org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext) {
   String path = ((org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)externalContext .getContext()).getDocBase();
}
```

But this this is in my opinion not a solution as you're highly dependend on tomcat's internals. Following issues remain:
* you have no guarantee that it's really an instance of `StandardContext`
* if this works for a given tomcat version, it may stop working without announcement in future
* in any case it does not work on any other app server

If just worte done this answer as you have discover by debuging this field. In general it's a very bad practice to debug some code you access though an API (here servlet API) and then find a way to access som internals not properly provided by this API, even if it's theoretically possible.

Comment: No, it is not. It returns `ServletContext`. See also API doc: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getContext%28%29

Comment: I've been working quite hard on finding this, so, a good way to see if something may be accessible is debugging if it is there. 
I don't want to get this exact variable, is just that it is there so it may be accessible from another class.

Comment: I agree with BalusC that API only insures that we have access to something thats implements SevletContext interface. And this does not give us access to a path on app server besides getRealPath() that you have mentioned. So the only way here is to make some presumptions about the app server as I suggested, but that is really not recommended.

Comment: Perhaps tell us what is the motivation to obtain this path and we may help you to find a way to solve it in a kindly manner.

Comment: As I commented before: "I'm doing an auto-update system, so I need to get the current war in orther to apply some patches to it. Therefore I need the current war file path."